Creating a Comprehensive Dataset of Bugs with Associated Reports, Commits, and Forum Posts for Deep Learning/Machine Learning
For a college project, I need to create a dataset that includes multiple bugs, with each bug having a bug report, GitHub commit, and Stack Overflow post associated with it. I’m looking for methods to link these elements together,considering similarity scoring techniques like BM25. Any additional suggestions?
